# How to delete Excel row if 2 columns have same value on different rows?

Tags: excel

I am wondering if I am able to delete a row in Excel if the values for columns C&D are the same on different rows, however, there is other data on the row that is dofferent in each row..

I.E.

```
 Row 1: C=EDDF, D=EGLL, E=SID
 Row 2: C=YSSY, D=YMML, E=DCT
 Row 3: C=EDDF, D=EGGL, E=STAR
 Row 4: C=YSSY, D=YMML, E=WPT
```

The file is a lot more complicated than that and has many rows (23,000), is there any way I can make it so that, for the one above, only row 1&2 remain

So 3 & 4 are deleted even though the value in E is different

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a formula to determine if a value in column C or D appears anywhere above.
Delete rows where `COUNTIF()` value is 1 or more:

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

Here's a screenshot of the formulas:

[image: Screenshot of worksheet formulas]